# Why did my earnings report change after two month?

Tags: youtube, youtube-monetization

As you can see, there's a big difference between the two reports. In the month of Nov, the report showed the right amount but now the report is changed! What's going on?

First report:
[image]

Second report:

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I view my ACTUAL earned YouTube Revenue?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111317/88163), [YouTube monetization - monetization turned on, but no revenue ever shown](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/41190/88163)

Comment: @Rubén I don't think those questions are related because in my case, the report is changed and that's illegal. In the past, it shows $35.73 and now it shows $10.35 They change the (History) which can never be changed.

Comment: I added the links as related, because these questions are about Youtube monetization reports, not because they were "duplicates".

Comment: @user2824371 This is confusing then, because the way you have the photos, it seems as though the $10.35 statement happened first and you later got one for $35.73.  Honestly, I'm not sure how much help we can actually be unless, in the small off-chance, someone else has seen this before.  Probably best to contact Google directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking Youtube community, They said:

> It's a glitch, and is being worked on

I hope they can solve it asap as the glitch is still going on. The earnings in the report dropped again from around $10 to $6. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Even if the earnings are (Estimated) they should roughly reflect the real values or it's better not to provide us with a report than providing us with a misleading one.

**Reference:**

https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/1409053?hl=en